# how to get notification when app auto sign out and clean data when close

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

My apps develop using ionic framework and use Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notification.
my apps will automatically sign out and clear data when close the apps. 
how about the firebase token? Did the firebase token assign to the apps? 
Did the firebase token deleted when clear the data? If the firebase token assign to apps how did the fcm find specific user by ID to sent notification when the apps use same token but use by multiple user.

Thanks in advance for answering

Comment: How do you honestly think anyone can answer your question without seeing any code?

Answer (score 1):

FCM token changes its token repeatedly. so there will be always a unique fcm token.